# UserTransaction jndi lookup failed when using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, websphere-liberty, completable-future

I have a code which does context lookup to get UserTransaction JNDI as `ctx.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction")`.

When I run this code without using `CompletableFuture`, it works as expected.

When working with `CompletableFuture` in async thread, it gives exception saying jndi lookup failed.

I tried to check if I can get the required JNDI from `global` scope, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the JNDI context is not propagated to the async thread, so when the `CompletionStage` attempts to execute the JNDI lookup, it has no context, so it doesn't know which component it is in and thus fails.

There is a very detailed explanation of context propagation and how to do it effectively in Open Liberty (which is the underlying product for WebSphere Liberty) at https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.8/microprofile-context-propagation.html - I'd highly suggest reading it.

Certain Java/Jakarta/MicroProfile APIs will allow you to specify the async service (`ExecutorService`) to use for the async operation. If possible, you can pass it an instance of `ManagedExecutorService` which should propagate contexts (like JNDI, security, classloading, etc.) to the async thread. Otherwise, you may need to specify the managed executor service when constructing your `CompletionStage`.

Answer (score 2):

CompletableFutures often run on the JDK's ForkJoinPool rather than application server managed threads, and so lack access to services provided by the application server.  MicroProfile Context Propagation (available in Liberty) solves this problem by giving you a way to create CompletableFutures that run on the Liberty thread pool and with access to application component context.

In server.xml,

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>mpContextPropagation-1.2</feature> <!-- 1.0 is also valid -->
  <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
  <feature>jdbc-4.2</feature> <!-- or some other feature that participates in transactions -->
  ... other features
</featureManager>
```

In your application,

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.context.ManagedExecutor;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.context.ThreadContext;
...
ManagedExecutor executor = ManagedExecutor.builder()
                           .propagate(ThreadContext.APPLICATION)
                           .build();

CompletableFuture<?> f = executor.supplyAsync(() -> {
    UserTransaction tx = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    ...
});

...
executor.shutdown();
```

If you don't want to construct a new ManagedExecutor, Liberty will also let you cast an EE Concurrency ManagedExecutorService to ManagedExecutor and use that.  For example,

```
ManagedExecutor executor = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutor");
```

It should also be noted that with a ManagedExecutor, the application context is made available to dependent stages as well as the initial stage, allowing you to perform the lookup in a dependent stage such as the following if you prefer:

```
executor.supplyAsync(supplier).thenApplyAsync(v -> {
    UserTransaction tx = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    ...
});
```

Comment: No, per the ManagedExecutor JavaDoc, the ManagedExecutor is, "A container-managed executor service that creates instances of CompletableFuture, which it backs as the default asynchronous execution facility, both for the CompletableFuture itself as well as all dependent stages created from it, as well as all dependent stages created from those, and so on."  Therefore, you do not supply any executor. All of the async completion stage action will run on the ManagedExecutor rather than the JDK's unmanaged ForkJoin threads.

Comment: Regarding your second question about the `supplier`, you can put whatever you want there. You could use the supplier from the first example's supplyAsync if you like.  I was just trying to get the point across that the ManagedExecutor will cover every dependent stage (supplyAsync, thenApplyAsync, and all others) if you create the CompletableFuture from it.  Whereas if you just put a managed executor service into a *Async executor argument, you will get non-deterministic behavior depending on where the prior CompletionStage happens to be running when it invokes submit on the executor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll update the answer to split that example into two parts, each illustrating the respective information that I'm trying to convey here.